# make all threads sleep linux/unix

Tags: linux, unix, sleep, thread-sleep

I am writing a program in linux/unix where I want to make all threads sleep, calling from one of the threads (of course including that one too). How can I do it?

`sleep()` only sleeps the calling process/thread, I want all of these to sleep.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lazy solution is to fork a child process and send a STOP signal to the parent, which will suspend the parent task.

```
pid_t apid = fork();
if (apid == 0) { /* Child */
    kill(getppid(), SIGSTOP);
    sleep(60);
    kill(getppid(), SIGCONT);
    exit(0);
} else if (apid > 0) { /* Parent */
    int state;
    waitpid(apid, &state, 0);
} else { /* error */
    perror("fork");
}
```

It may not quite do what you want, but it's the lazy way.

Comment: thanks for ur efforts.. but is there any way to do this for, say, some 10 different threads; all of which can be paused( or made to sleep) from one of the thread.

Comment: Not easily doable for a selected subset of threads. The only way you can accomplish it is by some mutex/lock/semaphore in each of the threads that you want to suspend.